# Todo App Example: Console doesn't show errors yet app doesn't work

Tags: redux, react-redux

Link to the git repo: https://github.com/todonoshow

I suspect the issue is related to the connection between the reducer and the container. In dir: src/containers/TodoList.js, I called:

`mapStateToProps = state => ({ state: state.todos })`

and

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList)`

But I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about passing what the todos reducer returns to the container.

App's behavior: Layout shows up but nothing happens when I click 'Add Todo' after filling the input field.

Expected behavior: Input from the input field to show up as a list item part of an unordered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<button>` must be wrapped within `<form>` as children, otherwise `onSubmit` will not even be called.

```
<form ...>
  <button ... />
</form>
```

p.s. using `ref` and direct DOM manipulation is discouraged in React.

Comment: Man, I've been fiddling with this code for hours. Thank you.